# Unity: How to lerp the color of only a single char within a block of text?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an icon I want to appear exactly at the end of a paragraph. For example:

```
You throw the ice cube at the monster.

The monster falls over dead. *
```

where `*` represents the icon I want to appear at the end. This can be any char or image converted to a sprite.

This icon must flash in color to indicate a picture is still loading and can't be moused over yet. The rest of the text should not flash in color.

Only two approaches come to mind:

1. Use rich text: Cannot lerp via rich text unless you constantly change the `<color>` string which I imagine must be extremely inefficient and freeze the game
2. Represent the icon separately from the text: I can lerp this easily, but am unable to determine the *position* of the icon relative to the text. I could just always put it below, but that wastes space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a `TMP_Text` (e.g. `TextMeshProUGUI`) you can go through the

```
TMP_TextInfo textInfo = yourText.textInfo;
```

The [`TMP_TextInfo`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@3.2/api/TMPro.TMP_TextInfo.html) holds all kind of information about the displayed text. E.g. the

```
TMP_LineInfo lastLine = textInfo.lineInfo[textInfo.lineCount - 1];
```

From that [`TMP_LineInfo`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@3.2/api/TMPro.TMP_LineInfo.html) you can now get e.g. the

```
float width = lastLine.width;
```

Having that information you should be able to go with option 2 and position an individual icon/text accordingly